# Content type text/markdown won't apply

Tags: php

I set page content type to `Content-Type: text/markdown`, output string should be **bold** but it's shown the raw string : `**bold**`

These are HTTP headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/markdown; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 17:30:35 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=qf3bsgt8l2ao97vh9650mq9e30; expires=Tue, 12-Nov-2013 19:30:35 GMT; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.7
```

*I also used text/x-markdown although it's deprecated.*

Comment: Which browser do you use? I don't know any which supports Markdown rendering.

Comment: You still need the receiver to be able to parse and format markdown automatically. At least Chrome can't do it.

Comment: @ComFreek google chrome

Comment: @AlexanderKuzmin oh really? so how should I work with this content type!

Comment: @revo You need to setup another "layer" of rendering/processing. A browser can usually only display HTML. Create a normal website which fetches and displays the data using JavaScript.

Comment: Makes more sense to me to just convert it server-side and serve it as regular ol' *HTML...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web browsers don't understand Markdown syntax natively. You need to use a Markdown parser library to convert your markup to HTML.

There are a whole ton to choose from. Here is a good starting point for PHP:

http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/

From your cookie header it looks like you're using the Laravel framework? In that case you probably want to look at the ready made bundles:

http://bundles.laravel.com/search/tag/Markdown

If you don't want to do this server-side, you could also convert your content with javascript:

https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js