# Setting "Content-Disposition" in php.ini

Tags: php

I sometimes use built-in PHP webserver locally and would like to set certain files to be handled as 'inline' when accessing through browsers (e.g. markdown). Is there a way to set Content-Disposition header for text/markdown type?

Comment: May be this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936445/content-type-text-markdown-wont-apply

Comment: @Noman Browsers now can support markdown files. Also it suggests using third-party tools, but not how to provide content with specific header

Comment: I use chrome extensions to parse the markdown files, and I can view them without problems accessing locally. However when accessing markdown files through built in php webserver they are downloaded instead.